# Is there any way to load analytics-dashboard wso2 with mssql DB?

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager, mssql-jdbc

I am using the MSSQL database for WSO2 API manager 3.2.0 and want to use analytics. When I changed the database to MSSQL, this error appeared. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you started the Dashboard? What errors do you see in the logs?

Comment: Cannot connect to JDBC URL jdbc:sqlserver:. Failed due to Failed to get driver instance

Comment: Have you added the JDBC driver? Please check https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#step-5-include-third-party-libraries-and-database-drivers

Comment: Yes, I have. But the dashboard appears with an error that I showed in the picture.

Comment: Yes, I added the JDBC driver in wso2 but not in analytics

Comment: You need to add it to wso2am-analytics as well

Comment: I added, but the error appeared again

Comment: Do you still get the `Failed to get driver instance` error in logs? or only the UI error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the MSSQL JDBC driver to the `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/lib` directory to use MSSQL as the external database for Analytics. I have tried with `mssql-jdbc` version `8.2.2.jre8`. Since `mssql-jdbc` depends on OSGi Service JDBC you will need to add that jar as well to the `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/lib` directory. You may use the following links to download the jars,

OSGi Service JDBC - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.service.jdbc/1.0.1

Microsoft JDBC Driver For SQL Server  - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/8.2.2.jre8

If you still face issues after adding the above jars, please add the complete stack trace related to the error. You can find the logs in the `carbon.log` file located at `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/wso2/worker/logs`.

Comment: Sanoj, I think you can copy the non-osgi driver to `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/jars` then you shouldn't need the OSGI dependencies. Or you can simply copy the OSGIed driver from APIM dropins directory(APIM_HOME/repository/components/dropins) and copy it to the `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/lib` directory. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Yes, we can follow that approach as well @ycr. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @sanoJ 
 this error now appears: "Error getting SSO auth URL","bundle.js:110          POST https://localhost:9643/login/analytics-dashboard 500 (Internal Server Error)".      how do I solve it?

Comment: @ycr this error now appears: "Error getting SSO auth URL","bundle.js:110 POST localhost:9643/login/analytics-dashboard 500 (Internal Server Error)". how do I solve it?